# Unexpected output due to file.readline() when using 'a+'

Tags: python, file-handling

Initially, I have a text file named `new_file` which stores `1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n`

I execute the following python program :

```py
f = open('new_file', 'a+')

f.write('\n'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 6)))
f.seek(0)

print(f.readlines())

f.seek(0)
f.write("\nFinal Line")

print(f.readlines())

f.close()
```

I expected the program to first add `1\n2\n3\n4\n5` to `new_file`, then print `['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', '1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5']`, then finally add `\nFinal Line` to `new_file` and print `['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', '1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', 'Final line']`

The changes to the file are as I expected, but what the program prints is this :

```
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', '1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5']
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', '1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5']
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: This likely has to do with buffering, as the file and the `TextIOWrapper` instance that wraps it have separate buffering. `f.seek` appears to affect the wrapper's buffer, but not the actual file, which has `Final Line` appended as the actual final line. The documentation mentions using the `reconfigure` method to disable the wrapper's buffering, but I haven't successfully produced your expected output yet.

Comment: What is your setup (O.S., version? )? the second print should print out an empty list - since you attempt to read when you are positioned at the end of the file/

Comment: @jsBueno I'm using Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: are you sure you are executing this code, and not making your changes in another folder and running old code from a previous (python) file? 
Your code, as is, should print an empty list on the second print. If you insert another `.seek(0)` before it, you should have the output you are expecting. 

This is quite deterministic.

Comment: (Testing on macOS.) Your last write doesn't end with a `\n`; if you call `f.flush()` to flush the write, then `f.readlines()` returns `[]`, indicating that the file pointer has been advanced to the very end of the file. It appears that `readlines` uses the `TextIOWrapper`'s buffer, while `f.write` only uses the underlying buffer. `f.flush()` "synchronizes" the the pointers to both the buffers.

Comment: When a file is opened in a+ mode, any seek is only going to affect the read position. Writes will always be at EOF (in other words appending) regardless of where you seek to. See [fopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)

Comment: @chepner I can somewhat comprehend that. Also, using `f.read()` instead of `f.readlines()` returns an empty string, as expected. Can you provide some resources related to buffers? I'm afraid I don't know much about them.

Comment: @chepner - do you think any chance this TextIOWrapper buffer is an Ubuntu thing? I am finding this rather strange. Fedora here, and the results are as I would expect (second print comes empty)

Comment: I've just been carefully reading the `io` docs; I won't claim to understand what's happening completely (or to have any knowledge about OS-specific handling). I will note that calling `f.tell()` seems to reset the underlying binary buffer as well; I was adding `print(f.tell()); print(f.buffer.tell()` after each read, write, and seek to see what was going on, and the order of the two `print` statements was significant.

Comment: As an aside, seeking and writing a text file seems like a bad idea in the first place. Regardless of the current position, writing a new line doesn't insert or replace exactly one line; it simply overwrites some number of bytes corresponding not the length of the new line. This will replace some or all of the "current" line, and possibly some of the following line(s) as well.

Comment: `f.write("\nFinal Line")` is still sitting in the output buffer.  It appears the seek to EOF happens when the file is flushed (leaving file pointer at EOF).  It also appears to be flushed if a seek occurs (which makes sense...it is documented that there should be an intervening seek between reads and writes).  An `f.seek(0)` added before the final readline, even without a flush, works as expected.

Comment: So in the OP's code, the write hasn't been flushed yet and the file pointer is still at the beginning of the file.  The 2nd readline reads the (unflushed) file again.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation for [fopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) if the file is opened in a+ mode "Output is **always** appended to the end of the file". Therefore you need to seek(0) immediately before the final call to *readlines()* in order to see the entire contents.

```
import os

try:
    os.remove("new_file")
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

with open('new_file', 'a+') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 6)))
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.readlines())
    # file pointer is now at EOF for reading
    f.write("\nFinal Line")
    # seek to BOF
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.readlines())
```

**Output:**

```
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5']
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', 'Final Line']
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't answer my question. Why is the code that I wrote behaving the way it is? Your code and my code have exchanged places for `f.write("\nFinal Line")` and `f.seek(0)`

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu I've edited the answer with a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using w+ mode instead of a+, and your second seek statement is on the wrong side of the second write statement.

To achieve your desired results your code should be:

```
f = open('new_file', 'w+')

f.write('\n'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 6)))
f.seek(0)

print(f.readlines())


f.write("\nFinal Line")
f.seek(0)

print(f.readlines())

f.close()
```

The output is:

```
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5']
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', 'Final Line']
```

If you must use a+ mode then your code should be:

```
import os

f = open('new_file2', 'a+')

f.write('\n'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 6)))
f.seek(0)

print(f.readlines())


f.write("\nFinal Line")
f.seek(0)

print(f.readlines())

f.close()
os.remove(f.name)
```

And the output will also be:

```
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5']
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', 'Final Line']
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm looking to understand why my code behaved the way it did. There wasn't a desired result I had in mind while writing it. Why the `f.readLines()` in my code is not displaying the 'Final Line' element is what I'm trying to ask through the question.

Comment: The reason it is not acting the way you expect is because you are using the a+ mode.  With that mode, the file remains in system memory and you get unexpected results because you are accessing an already altered object.  You need to either use the w+ mode as in my first response or if you must use the a+ mode you need to remove the file object from memory each time you run the code.  I will add that code to my answer.

Comment: `w+` may behave differently than `a+`, but this is not a reason to *use* `w+` instead `a+` if you don't want to wipe out the contents of the file.

Comment: The reason that it is not displaying the final line is because you never refresh the version of 'f' that is stored in memory for reading AFTER you write 'Final Line' to it.  Moving the f.seek(0) statement after the write statement forces a refresh of the version of 'f' stored for reading.

Comment: @chepner Correct but if he does not want to get anomalous results then he must wipe out the previously written contents of the file if he is going to use a+ mode.

Comment: Yes, but using `w+` absolutely does not not produce the OP's expected result, so it's not an answer to the *question*, regardless of what OP might actually be trying to achieve that led him to the question.

Comment: @chepner I also posted an answer showing him how to do it with a+.  Both of my answers (the one using w+ and the one using a+) produce what he showed as his expected result in his original question and with minimal alteration to his original code.